# Which server in the farm sends the email?

Tags: sharepoint-server, smtp

I entered "Outbound SMTP Server" address in Central Admin. Now I need to tell my SMTP server to accept emails from my farm. How do I find which server/IP address in the farm trying to send emails?

Comment: are you talking about the relay settings?

Comment: The initial request to your outbound server will be coming from whichever WFE the user is connected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint WFE are responsible to send the emails to user. I think you are talking about the relay setting. You should enter the WFE Ips their.

- IP addresses of Web Front End’s in you farm.
- But if you want to use all servers in the farm then select **all except the list below** option.